# It does not display the jquery timepicker

Tags: jquery, timepicker

I want to know why this code below is not displaying a button next to my "questiondurationpickerRow" textbox to be able to open up the trent richardson's timepicker. (I changed the code timepicker to trenttimepicker in the function and js file but don't worry about this because I know the function works but it does not appear when I include it in the insertQuestion(form) function).

Below is my code:

```
var qnum = 1;

function insertQuestion(form) {
            $('#questiondurationpickerRow').trenttimepicker({
                timeFormat: 'hh mm ss',
                hourGrid: 4,
                minuteGrid: 10,
                secondGrid: 10,
                showOn: 'button',
                buttonImage: "Images/clock.gif",
                buttonImageOnly: true
            });

    var $tr = $("<tr></tr>");
    var $qid = $("<td class='qid'>" + qnum + "</td>");
    var $duration = $("<td class='duration'></td>");

    $('#questiondurationpicker').each(function() {

        var $this = $(this);
        var $durationText =
        $("<input type='text' id='questiondurationpickerRow' readonly='readonly' />")
            .attr('name', $this.attr('name'))
            .attr('value', $this.val())

        $duration.append($durationText);
    });

    $tr.append($qid);
    $tr.append($duration)
    $('#qandatbl').append($tr);

    form.numberOfQuestions.value = qnum;

    ++qnum;
    $("#questionNum").text(qnum);
    form.questionText.value = "";
}
```

Comment: You must execute AGAIN the javascript code that attatches datepicker to elements with .datepicker css class, so the handler can show the date picker when you clic on the new inputs

Comment: So do you mean I need to include the jquery script tags in the function?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your code. Question: do you have more than one input with the same id?

Comment: I have two textboexes which are suppose to use the same trenttimepicker function (only differece is the id), one is called "questiondurationpicker" and the other is called "questiondurationpickerRow". The "questiondurationpicker" textbox is a readonly textbox where the values from the timepicker can be stored in while "questondurationpickerRow" recieves the data stored from the "questiondurationpicker" textbox but if user wants to change the duration in the "questiondurationpickerRow" textbox then they can by opeining up its own timepicker. Hoefully you understand :)

Answer (score 0):

See this link :

Visit : http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

It has better examples :

### Show Seconds, Minutes, or Hours

-showHour    Show the hour, default=true

-showMinute    Show the minute, default=true

-showSecond    Show the second, default=false

-showMillisec    Show the millisecond, default=false

```
$('#example5').datetimepicker({
showSecond: true,
showMillisec: true,
timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss:l'
});
```